Why can’t spacetime be projective?
I come from a pure mathematics background so I’m sure that there’s an obvious reason this cannot be the case, but it’s not obvious to me, however I haven’t found much discourse anywhere on the following question: is the topology of spacetime $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^4$?
In particular as a manifold $\mathbb{R}\mathbb{P}^4$ is locally Euclidean so on a small scale we wouldn’t see any immediate contradictions, and the notion of a point at infinity not only seemingly resolves black holes forming singularities but also the question of whether or not the universe is finite/infinite, being infinite but compact.
What immediately comes to mind is as a problem is the non-orientability of even-dimensional projective spaces, but it’s not immediately clear to me why this breaks anything.

Spacetime is not Euclidean but Lorentzian.

Unless I'm misunderstanding the compactness of the Universe was a given, but the infinitude of its extent is not (and depends on curvature).

"the notion of a point at infinity [...] seemingly resolves black holes forming singularities" How?

Projective space is homogeneous.  A point at infinity is no different from any other point.

I’m voting to close this question because the OP offers no reason to ask about ${\bf RP}^4$ as opposed to any of a myriad of other four-dimensional manifolds.

While I understand the vote to close, the question in the title seems perfectly reasonable, why there is little discussion about spacetimes with projective topology?The answer already posted, and the comments on it offer reasons why this structure would be problematic. It seems to me that the OP was at first motivated by dealing with things such as singularities. One could note that singularities are not points at infinity, but situations which cannot be described as points. The OP could ask another question on what is the difference between points at infinity and singularities.

@cesarulina:  I could be happy with a question along the lines of "which manifolds are candidates for spacetime?".  But breaking that into separate questions of the form "Is manifold X a candidate for spacetime?" (where in this case X=RP^4) strikes me as a recipe for madness.  One could flood the site with hundreds of such questions.

@WillO, that's a good point. Indeed the site would benefit from not allowing such restrictive questions. As a matter of fact, there is already a question titled "topology is cosmology" asking which topologies are allowed for cosmological spacetimes. As such I would second your vote to close

General relativity is a local theory. It describes the curvature and how it influences/is influenced by fields locally. But it does not prescribe the global geometry of spacetime. The same local curvatures can be compatible with wildly different manifolds.
The easiest example is a flat spacetime, which could just be $R^3\times R$ (if we separate out the time dimension). But it could also be a flat 3-torus, $T^3\times R$. Or even $R^3 \times S$, an infinite flat universe with cyclic time. There is nothing in GR determining which manifold it actually is. $RP^4$ is a totally valid choice.
However, the physics of the fields running on the manifold can put in constraints. In particular, it seems that non-orientability has troublesome implications for fields that break chiral symmetry. We have only observed or inferred left-chiral fermions and right-chiral antifermions participating in the charged weak interaction. Were the universe non-orientable this would not be possible since left-chiral fermions could travel around the universe and become right-chiral. So the restriction to orientable manifolds makes sense if chiral asymmetry is a thing.

Well, it can’t be $\Bbb{RP}^4$ for purely topological reasons, because it is compact but has Euler characteristic equal to $1$, so $\Bbb{RP}^4$ doesn’t carry any smooth Lorentzian metric (see here).

Since the OP asked about cosmological spacetimes, I think your answer would be even better if you explicitly mentioned that whether a cosmological spacetime is infinite or finite (in space or time) is to be determined by the Einstein Equations and the matter content, which I think you hinted at in the first paragraph, when talking about it being a local theory.

@peek-a-boo That is an answer to the question.
